# Magento Community Edition 1.7 Subtracting Tax Instead of Adding It

Tags: tax, shipping-tax

I recently had an extension installed professionally through another company (already contacted them) that caused some back-end glitching on my Magento e-commerce store. I was able to remedy most of the issues but this one is perplexing to the point I thought I would ask the Stack Exchange community. I have scoured all the settings in Sales->Tax and even experimented by changing settings to see if something happens, but I've come up with nothing. For some odd reason my store is subtracting the state tax instead of adding it. I am sure the vendor who installed it (aheadWorks will remedy the issue) but just in case they are lost/confused, I wanted to ask some of the experts. For those who want to see my problem live: Innov8tiveDesigns.com. It's doing this for literally all my products and I am just lost at this point.

[image: A screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 1):

Check your tax settings under

`System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings`

and set `Display Subtotal` to `Excluding Tax`

When doing this make sure you have selected the right store configuration scope.